# ASP.NET MVC application, <text> tag

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

In an ASP.NET MVC application I am working on, `<text>` tags are being used in a `.cshtml` file.

Example -

```
<text>some text</text>
```

What functionality do they provide? I can not find *any* reference to them on the interweb :)

Thanks!

Comment: I think they dont any functionality, instead they are used to write content on to the page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The are kinda the opposite of the @ tags...

Standard in views you are in "HTML-mode", you can then use a Razor-block like this:

```
@{
  //Razor code
}
```

Razor will detect HTML-tags in a razor block and render that but sometimes you just need to show the literal text. That's where the  tag comes in... It switches back to HTML-mode without using an actual HTML-tag...

So some text will render that exact text (WITHOUT the  tag>) in your view:
Convaluted example, but this code:

```
<div>
you have
@{
 if(numItems == 0)
 {
   <text>no</text>
 }
 else
 {
   @numItems
 }


}
items
</div>
```

Will render "You have no items" or "you have 5 items" for example...

Comment: I think it's misleading to say that `<text>....</text>` is an *opposite* to `@`, since they are the same as using `@:`.

Comment: The <text> tag is for multiple lines: @: only does a single line. Comparable to /* */ and // commenting...

Answer (score 2):

This element for identifying content explicitly. You can read information about this here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

Comment: It is worth highlighting that (as mentioned in that article) that `<text>...</text>` is completely interchangable with using `@:`.

Answer (score 0):

The `<text>` explicitly tells the Razor view engine that this is text and not code. I use it when the renderer struggles with the page or if the html needs to be tightly controlled.

For example

```
<div id="content" @if (ViewData["PageLayout"] != null){
<text>class="@ViewData["PageLayout"].ToString()</text><text>"</text>
}>
```

See [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx) from Scott Gu.

Comment: Thanks for the response NikolaiDante! Can I ask what you mean by "when the renderer struggles with the page"?

Comment: @ABogus Sometimes when parsing a Razor view, it will try and interpret your standard html mark up as code instead of text. Using `<text>` makes the intention explicit.